# Print to Log using Go Language Simple HTTP Server

Tags: go

I am trying to log the IP address of the requestor, what METHOD they are using and what file they are requesting. But for some reason it only outputs on the terminal and doesn't save it to logfile.txt...

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "log"
  "encoding/json"
  "io/ioutil"
)

type Options struct {
  Path string
  Port string
}

func Log(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("%s %s %s\n", r.RemoteAddr, r.Method, r.URL)
    handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}

func main() {

  op := &Options{Path: "./", Port: "8001"}

  data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./config.json")

  json.Unmarshal(data, op)

  http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(op.Path)))
  err := http.ListenAndServe(":" + op.Port, Log(http.DefaultServeMux))
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your script as-is (logging to the console) is just what I needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `Log` function, you are using [`fmt.Printf`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) not [`fmt.Fprintf`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf).

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

var logFile *os.File

func Log(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(logFile, "%s %s %s\n", r.RemoteAddr, r.Method, r.URL)
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func main() {
    var err error
    logFile, err = os.Create("logfile.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Log file create:", err)
        return
    }
    defer logFile.Close()
}
```

Comment: I added FprintF(w ... but how can I direct that to a file such as logs.txt? (Thanks for the help btw.)

Comment: See my revised answer for an outline of a solution.